# Como construir um kernel size para um filtro MedianBlur opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Eu tenho esse filtro MedianBlur no opencv:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Resources/land.jpg')
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


def empty(a):
    pass

# ------- CREATE TRACKBAR -------
cv2.namedWindow('Median Blur')
cv2.createTrackbar('Median', 'Median Blur', 0, 10, empty)

while True:
    m_pos = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Median', 'Median Blur')

    imgMedianBlur = cv2.medianBlur(imgGray, 5)
    cv2.imshow('Median Blur', imgMedianBlur)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Eu coloquei um parametro fixo `5` no kernel size `ksize`:

```py
imgMedianBlur = cv2.medianBlur(imgGray, 5)
```

Estou tentando colocar esse valor dinamicamente com a posição do TrackBar:

```py
m_pos = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Median', 'Median Blur')
# recebendo a pos do trackbar
```

Mas claro que colocando `m_pos` (abaixo) não funciona:

```py
imgMedianBlur = cv2.medianBlur(imgGray, m_pos)
```

com esse erro:

```py
error: (-215:Assertion failed) (ksize % 2 == 1) && (_src0.dims() <= 2 )
```

Como eu construo esse `kernel size` baseado na posição do `trackbar`?

estou usando - Pycharm Community 2019.3 - Mac - Python 3.7 - module: opencv-python 4.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido. Bastou deixar o `m_pos` ímpar, como indicado no erro `(ksize % 2 == 1)`.

O código ficou assim:

```py
m_pos = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Median', 'Median Blur')
    if(m_pos % 2 != 1):
        m_pos = m_pos + 1

    imgMedianBlur = cv2.medianBlur(imgGray, m_pos)
```

Vou deixar aqui a resposta, caso alguém precise tb!